# Laravel "\Request::route()->getName()" give null results

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel with Spatie Permissions package, and it's working fine!

I'm trying also to use  the `Authorizable` trait for managing the Roles and Permissions.

The problem seems to be `$routeName = explode('.', \Request::route()->getName());`.

I expect to have from  `\Request::route()->getName()` the result `posts.index` but I have null.

`\Request::route()->getName()` works only if I defined the property "name" into the route by using `->name('posts/index')` (and the result is `posts/index` )

why `\Request::route()->getName()`  is null in my app ? What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you defined route name in web.php?

Comment: Why do you `explode`?

Answer (score 0):

To get route name ,you need to use

```
$name = Route::currentRouteName();
```

and `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;`

`Request::route()->getName()` works only for laravel < 5.*

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
   Route::currentRouteName(); //use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

but also you can get action of route by

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but the first suggested solution give me a null value, the second suggested solution give me this result: "App\Http\Controllers\PostController@edit"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why are you getting this but the route must have `->name()` (if you want to use route names) if it was not a resource route.